# Probability of extracting a multiple of 2 of the natural numbers.

Tags: probability

I have a doubt. (I do not know if it can be resolved)
What is the probability of taking a multiple of 2 from the natural numbers?
Intuitively, as odd and even numbers form naturals, one would tend to think that this probability is 1/2, but if we use P(multiply of 2) = favorable cases / total cases, we obtain an indefinite form (infinitely numbers / infinitely numbers).

Similarly, what would be the probability of obtaining a multiple of 11 of the natural numbers?

In this case, the sample space is the natural numbers (which are countable infinite)

Comment: You probably think of the natural numbers ordered as $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots$. But what happens if you think of them with e.g. ordered as: $0,11,1,22,3,33,4,44,5,55,6,66,7,77,8,88,9,99,10,110,12,121,\dots$? Then our intuition will say that the probability of obtaining a multiple of $11$ is $\frac12$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to define a uniform distribution over natural numbers.
In situations like this, people reason using [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density), which is almost the notion that you arrived at on your own.

Basically, instead of talking about the probability of an event on the natural numbers, you consider the probability of the event on the finite set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, and then take $n \to \infty$.

So for "what is the probability of drawing a multiple of $2$ from the natural numbers," we consider "what is the probability of drawing a multiple of $2$ from the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, and then take $n \to \infty$. In this case, $\frac{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{n} \to \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I just calculated and arrived at P (multiply of 11) = 1/11. It would be correct?

Comment: @eraldcoil Yes, correct if you are using natural density.